# Are HSTS headers necessary if the server does URL rewrite of incoming HTTP traffic to HTTPS?

Tags: security, iis, https, hsts

If I disable HTTP, and add an URL rewrite on the server to rewrite all incoming URLS from http to https, should I still add HSTS headers? What would that accomplish? I have a customer requesting this.

Comment: HTTP/HTTPS redirection and HSTS contribute to the same goal (enforcing HTTPS) but from different angles (server side, and browser side). So if your customer asks for that, you can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If HTTP is disabled, HTTP cannot be rewritten to HTTPS. HTTP must be enabled to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the server side.
When HSTS is enabled, the browser redirects from http to https. HTTP can be disabled.

If HTTP is disabled (port 80 is closed) the browser should not send HTTP requests, but if there is an attacker on the network path like MITM, HTTP requests can actually be sent. .. In this case, the attacker is forced to send a request such as http://example.com/ from the victim's browser. The attacker on the network path could eavesdrop or tamper with it and relay it to the server. HSTS prevents such attacks.

If HTTP is disabled, an attacker on the network path can tamper with cookies. The attacker can send a request to http://example.com/ from the victim's browser in the same way as above, and return a response on the intermediate device (Web server). At that time, Set-Cookie headers can be added to the response. Subsequent requests to https://exmaple.com/ will enable thes cookies.